# 'Equatable' cannot be automatically synthesized in an extension

Tags: swift, swift4, protocol-extension

This works:

```
// Conformance to protocol correctly synthesized by compiler 
struct MyStruct: Equatable { 
}
```

This doesn't:

```
struct MyStruct { 
}
// Doesn't work, even though the extension is in the same file
extension MyStruct: Equatable {
}
```

The error is very clear:

> implementation of 'Equatable' cannot be automatically synthesized in an extension

My concern is that according to Swift's proposal [SE-0185](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0185-synthesize-equatable-hashable.md#requesting-synthesis-is-opt-in), this should be allowed:

> **SE-0185: Synthesizing `Equatable` and `Hashable` conformance**
>
> Users must opt-in to automatic synthesis by declaring their type as `Equatable` or `Hashable` without implementing any of their requirements. This conformance must be part of the original type declaration **or in an extension in the same file** (to ensure that private and fileprivate members can be accessed from the extension).

It says this was implemented in Swift 4.1 ([apple/swift#9619](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/9619)).

However, when trying to compile, I get the error previously shown. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, it fails with these two versions of swift I've got:

- `Swift version 4.1-dev (LLVM 260a172ffb, Clang cd84be6c42, Swift 05b1b2be7c)`
- `Swift version 4.2-dev (LLVM d30879863e, Clang 041fd44ebe, Swift b08fb12358)`

Am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Probably [this issue](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6803).

Comment: ...which was implemented about [2 weeks ago](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/16376).

Comment: This is a bug in swift and logged [here](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6101).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Good news**

The most recent dev. snapshot from June 5th, 2018 works as expected:

- [Trunk (master) Development Snapshot](https://swift.org/builds/development/ubuntu1604/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2018-06-05-a/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2018-06-05-a-ubuntu16.04.tar.gz) (Ubuntu 16.04)

---

**Bad news**

Most recent -release- version [4.1.2](https://swift.org/builds/swift-4.1.2-release/ubuntu1604/swift-4.1.2-RELEASE/swift-4.1.2-RELEASE-ubuntu16.04.tar.gz) is not working.

Comment: trunk link is not found now